# how to install Bazel into Alpine container using apk

Tags: alpine

I want to install Bazel (version 5.1.1) into an Alpine container using apk.

I tried this command and got this error:

```
% apk add bazel=5.1.1
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  bazel (no such package):
    required by: world[bazel=5.1.1]
```

Removing the version doesn't help...

```
% apk add bazel
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  bazel (no such package):
    required by: world[bazel]
```

Adding "--no-cache" to the apk command also doesn't help.

Can anyone explain the cause of the error and how to make the installation happen correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I visited the packages menu on Alphine website and bazel is in the testing repository.

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=bazel*&branch=edge&repo=&arch=&maintainer=

Can you please check `/etc/apk/repositories` to make sure that testing repo is enable if you want to use the testing repo.

Comment: Thanks! Appending http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing to the end of /etc/apk/repositories allowed Bazel to be installed.